# FAQ has been replaced with Help

Tags: discussion

It seems that SE has replaced FAQ with [help](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter). So we need to find a replacement to referring new users to FAQ or directing them to the front page of the help page can be confusing since the scope is not defined on the first page of the help page. It needs one more click to get to [our part](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) of it.

[Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center)

Comment: Can't we just point people to our meta question ?

Comment: @Suresh, yes, we can. Do we need to clean up that FAQ?

Comment: citing the link you just gave seems reasonable: [what topics can I ask about here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)